# iOS unwind a pop-over modal view used by 2 view controllers to its presenting view

Tags: iphone, ios, uistoryboardsegue

I'm sure there's an easy answer to this, but I just can't seem to find it (searching wrong terms, maybe). Anyway, i'm sure there is a better way to do this:

I'm calling a modal view from my homeViewController (first screen when the app loads) that allows a user to add new items). Pretty straight-forward. I also call the SAME modal view from the detailViewController when editing an item.

Now, I have a cancel action (on the Add modal view) that looks like this (in homeViewController):

```
- (IBAction)cancel:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"CancelInput"]) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

This works just fine, However, if I call the same modal view from the detail controller and click this SAME button it doesn't unwind the modal to the detail page, but rather to the homeViewController. Ideally I want the app to unwind to the detail screen in this case. I managed to solve it by placing the above code in the detailViewController as well, and it works. but I feel there must be a better solution. This is a small bit of code, but the code for saving will be much longer, and the repetition of code seems unnecessary. What's a better way to do this? Should I add the cancel method to the app delegate? That seems like it would quickly get cluttered, and breaks (in my mind) the MVC pattern.

Also, I'm using storyboards for this app... For what that's worth.

Thanks